# Is there a way to override ALL node functions from one npm module to run a custom function at the end of the original function's execution?

Tags: node.js, logging, node-modules

Example: I have an NPM module that I import:

`const ex = require('ex');`

And I use it in a bunch of different places:

`const response1 = await ex.doThis()`
`const response2 = await ex.doThat()`

At the end of each function, I also want to log a specific part of the response for all methods in `ex`. Is there a way to 'override' `doThis` and `doThat` (and all other functions) such that that I can simply log something after the function is done running without having to manually add a log every time I call those functions?

I'm thinking about making a wrapper over `ex` and re-exporting it, but I'm not sure how to modify the functions so that first they run themselves as is and then run my custom log function from the response they return. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will override all the methods of a package and execute `console.log('DONE');` after the method execution is done. You'll have a little more work to do to handle promises, but that shouldn't be an issue.

```js
const path = require('path');


function override(module) {

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(module).forEach((property) => {

    if (typeof module[property] === 'function') {
      const method = module[property];

      module[property] = function () {
        // You need to handle promises here
        const res = method.apply(module, arguments);
        console.log('DONE'); // Replace this with your logging function
        return res;
      };
    }
  });

}

override(path);

console.log(path.extname('https://www.google.com'));
```